# Can I open a photo in a text message without using my data?

Tags: hardware

I got a Motorola Razr-V phone and received a text with an attached photo. Is it possible to open using Wi-Fi,not my phone data?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you are recieving images in a text message it only uses your data to download it or to show up in your text messages. Opening the image after it has showed up in the message doesn't require internet connection of any type. So far the only phones I am aware of that allow you to use WiFi to download images in a text are the iPhones, so I am not certain if Android based phones are capable of that.